# Kivy Redis and Buildozer

Tags: android, redis, kivy

I built a Kivy application using kivy.storage.redisstore.
It ran on windows7 and ubuntu as clients using PyCharm and source code (not as exe files).
I tried to pack it with Buildozer and I didn't get any error massages, but the application didn't run on Android only a keyboard appeared. 
In the buildozer.spec I use these lines:

```
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,rdb
requirements = kivy,redis
```

Many thanks;
GadH.

Comment: So you didn't add the INTERNET permission? That is, of course, necessary to connect to a server. If adding that permission does not resolve the issue, please post the relevant output from `buildozer android logcat`, including the Exception or error info.

Comment: I added the internet permission, but still it doesn't run. Logcat doesn't give me any information about the problem. I still get the keyboard looks like the application is waiting for a password but I can't insert one because entering pass and pressing on the enter button doesn't clear the keyboard from the screen.

Comment: how did you imported Redis on kivy launcher or how you were able to start redis-server on mobile/kivy launcher

Comment: I run the Redis server on a PC. In the buildozer in the requirements I added redis. I added INTERNET permissions as well. but still it doesn't work.